# Why ArrayPointer gives segmentation default?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault

In my code, when I changed `void myFunc(int arrayInput[3][2])` to `void myFunc(int **arrayInput)`, I got segmentation fault for line 5, why? How can I used array pointer instead of array with fixed dimensions? Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int myArray[3][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};

int main2() {
  myFunc(myArray);
  return 0;
}

void myFunc(int arrayInput[3][2]) {

  printf("Line 1: %x\n",arrayInput);
  printf("Line 2: %x\n",arrayInput + 1);
  printf("Line 3: %x\n",*arrayInput);
  printf("Line 4: %x\n",*(arrayInput+1));
  printf("Line 5: %d\n",*(*(arrayInput + 1) + 0));

}
```

Comment: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little on the **why**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int myArray[3][2] = { { 1, 2}, { 3, 4}, { 5, 6}};

void myFunc ( int array[3][2], int **ptrptr) {
    printf ( "   : %p   **: %p\n", (void*)array, (void*)ptrptr);
    printf ( "[0]: %p   **: %p\n", (void*)*(array + 0), (void*)*(ptrptr + 0));
    printf ( "[1]: %p   **: %p\n", (void*)*(array + 1), (void*)*(ptrptr + 1));
    printf ( "[1][0]: %d\n",*(*(array + 1) + 0));
}

int main ( void) {
    printf ( "myArray: %p\n", (void*)&myArray);
    myFunc ( myArray, myArray);
    return 0;
}
```

This program passes `myArray` as an array and as a pointer to pointer.
The compiler warns me that pointer to pointer is an incompatible type.

Output:

```
myArray: 0x55d518e9e010
   : 0x55d518e9e010   **: 0x55d518e9e010
[0]: 0x55d518e9e010   **: 0x200000001
[1]: 0x55d518e9e018   **: 0x400000003
[1][0]: 3
```

The first line gives the address of `myArray` in `main`.
The second line shows that in `myFunc`, both pointers point to `myArray`.
The next line shows why the types are incompatible. `*(array + 0)` points to a valid address. `*(ptrptr + 0)` points to an invalid address. Instead of the address in another pointer, it shows the two integers of `myArray[0]` as an address on a little endian system.
The last line shows the value at the dereferenced addresses of `array`. Attempting to dereference the invalid addresses in `ptrptr` leads to disaster.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but what's happening here? What is `0x200000001`? I also tried `void* myPtr = *(ptrptr + 0); printf ( "Indirect: %p   Direct: %p\n", (void*) &myPtr, (void*)&*(ptrptr + 0));`, but why Indirect and Direct have different addresses?

Comment: Thanks. Now I got both of them `0x200000001`. But I still have no idea where `0x200000001` comes from and what is its meaning. Would you please explain further a bit?

Answer (score 2):

A double pointer doesn't represent a 2D array.
What you can try doing is allocating your 2 dimensional arrays dynamically like so

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void myFunc(int** array);
int main() {
    int** myarray = malloc(3*sizeof(int*));
    for(int x = 0; x < 3;++x){
        myarray[x] = malloc(2*sizeof(int));
    }
    for(int col = 0; col < 3; ++ col){
        for(int row = 0; row < 2; ++row){
            myarray[col][row] = col+row;
        }
    }
    myFunc(myarray);
    
    
    for(int x = 0; x < 3;++x){
        free(myarray[x]);
    }
    free(myarray);
  return 0;
}

void myFunc(int** arrayInput) {

  printf("Line 1: %p\n",arrayInput);
  printf("Line 2: %p\n",arrayInput + 1);
  printf("Line 3: %p\n",*arrayInput);
  printf("Line 4: %p\n",*(arrayInput+1));
  printf("Line 5: %d\n",*(*(arrayInput + 1) + 0));
}
```